How to disable the midpoints of polygon created by Mapbox-gl-draw
I use mapbox-gle-draw to create polygons on the map and the default behavior creates a midpoint that allow me later when clicking on it to add new point
I want to disable the default behavior and remove that midpoint
enter image description here
I want to remove the midpoints created by default in mapbox-gl-draw

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

When you create the draw instance:
const result: MapboxDraw = new MapboxDraw({
    modes: {
        ...
    },
    ...
    styles: CustomStyle,
});

There is a styles property to which a custom style sheet can be assigned.
This file gives a template for the styling of Mapbox Draw layers. There you can identify the layer for polygon-midpoints:
id: 'gl-draw-polygon-midpoint'

It's easy to let these midpoints now "disappear" by changing the filter so it never returns true:
['all', ['==', '$type', 'Point'], ['==', 'meta', 'midpoint'], ["==", true, false]

Please test this out ☝ because I haven't done so 
This should also work:
paint: {
  'circle-radius': 3 -> 0,
  'circle-color': 'rgb(242, 98, 110)' -> rgba(242, 98, 110, 0),
},

A more professional adjustment would be to create a custom drawing style (derived from SimpleSelect & DirectSelect) which leaves out the midpoints all together as you desire. Take a closer look into the documentation of Mapbox draw (custom styles) at GitHub
Here are two examples of CustomDrawModes for a circle which should help get you going, explore and implement yours:

CircleMode 1
CircleMode 2

Furthermore dig into the source code of MapboxDraw to investigate and learn to support your custom made draw modes (triangle? hexagon? donut? etc.)

I tried to implement the code for changing the styles of the mid point but it did not work properly
but the corner points of the polygon disappeared

Did they both disappear? Or only the corner points?

both disappeared and the polygon made not clickable

Then you should go for a CustomDrawMode derived from or based on the Polygon draw mode (Simple & DirectSelect?). An example for a CustomDrawMode for a circle which I took as a starting point for learning to implement CustomDrawMode(s) is now added to the answer.
